# Fetching incorrect URL into database during upload of images in Firebase Database. Need some guidance.(Kotlin)

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin, image-uploading

I am trying to store the url in the `firebasedatabase`  of images i upload into the `firebase storage`.

I have tried some video guides but most of them are outdated.I am trying to use downloadUrl to fetch url but its not working. I am new to coding and i d appreciate any kind of advice. I have tried `Firebase` Documentation but i am unable to apply it into my code.

```
    if (mImageUri != null)
    {
        val fileName= edit_text_file_name.text.toString()
        val fileReference = mStorageRef!!.child(fileName + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri!!)
        )
        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

                val name = taskSnapshot.metadata!!.name
                val imageUrl= taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.toString()
```

The problem here is in the line above i think with val imageUrl

```
                writeNewImageInfoToDB(name!!, imageUrl)
                Toast.makeText(this@ActivityUpload, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Toast.makeText(this@ActivityUpload, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            .addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->
                val progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalByteCount)
                mProgressBar!!.progress = progress.toInt()
            }
```

I expect the above code to give me the URL of the image i uploaded but instead i get

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@5a826e5" in my database whereas i am
>   expecting a firebase url like
>   firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/-------`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@5a826e5
```

And not the actual url because this is the address from memory of your `downloadUrl` object which is of type `Task<Uri>` and **not** the actual Uri.

According to the official documentation regarding on how to [get a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url):

> After uploading a file, you can get a URL to download the file by calling the `getDownloadUrl()` method on the StorageReference:

```
val ref = storageRef.child(fileName + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri!!))
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file)

val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        task.exception?.let {
            throw it
        }
    }
    return@Continuation ref.downloadUrl
}).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUri = task.result
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the urlTask used?

Comment: Inside the `onComplete()` function. Does it work this way?

Comment: This method worked out for me, i had to make adjustments to my code. I was just confused about the useage of the val urlTask...

Comment: still didn't work for me...

Comment: a working solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061743/7795072